# "Illegal byte sequence" when trying to rm a file

Tags: macos, command-line, file

When I try running this command

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

I get this error:

```
rm: node_modules/core-js/core/function.js: Illegal byte sequence
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Something about that file name is causing `rm` to abort.  Can you erase it explicitly?

Comment: May be a "locales problem". You can try `LC_ALL=C rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: @Marc no i can't erase it explicitly too
@ Jean it's not working too

Comment: Could you try `LC_CTYPE=C && LANG=C && rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: I'd  boot to **macOS Recovery** and try deleting it from there.

Comment: None of them worked

Comment: Not even if you export it? `export LC_CTYPE=C && export LANG=C`

Comment: Where is this file? Is it on the Mac's main volume, an external disk (in which case what format is it), a server (what kind), or anything like that?

Comment: @DarwinOSX i exported them but not worked

Comment: @GordonDavisson there is in home of my user /home/mohammad/project_name/node_module...

Comment: /home/mohammad? macOS home directories are normally under /Users. Is your home directory on an NFS server or something?

Comment: @GordonDavisson sry I made a mistake. it is on /Users/mohammad/....

Comment: `rm` does not care about the file contents.  It cares about the directory contents.  Please show the result of attempting to delete the file explicitly.

Comment: @MarcWilson result:`The operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped. For each item, choose File > Get Info, make sure “Locked” is deselected, and then check the Sharing & Permissions section. When you are sure the items are unlocked and not designated as Read Only or No Access, try again.`

Comment: `rm` didn't say that.

Comment: @MarcWilson rm said : `rm: function.js: Illegal byte sequence`

Comment: Have to tried to run First Aid in the Disk Utility program?

Comment: @MartinR yes, i ran. it's ok. it not have any error